# ¿Cómo soluciono este problema de url amigables?

Tags: .htaccess, url

Lo que sucede es que estoy creando urls amigables, pero el problema es que me agrega una *query string* al final, por ejemplo esta es mi url:

```
http://url.com/url-amigable?query=url-amigable
```

Y quiero que sea así:

```
http://url.com/url-amigable
```

Y la url original es:

```
http://url.com/?query=url-amigable
```

Este es mi código de `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /?query=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1? [L]
```

El ? luego del %1 le dice a Apache que ya no procese el query string.

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, pero ahora me surge una duda, como le haría para permitir solo un query string específico como por ejemplo `id=12345`, como podría lograr eso

Comment: Usa RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(12345) [NC]   RewriteRule solo funcionará si la condición definida con RewriteCond se cumple.

Comment: Osea que con solo usar esa regla de hataccess puedo definir los querys permitidos solo por mi pagina, osea digamos este es mi url `http://url.com/url-amigable?id=12345`

Comment: Así es @AnimationsNow

Comment: Muchas gracias. Bueno al final descubrí que una regla de mi htaccess estaba interfiriendo en eso y lo solucione gracias a tu ejemplo, basto con solo agregarle este signo `?` de interrogación a mi regla y listo funciona a la perfección.